# Resolving "require"s when executing IronRuby from C#

Tags: c#, ironruby

I'm attempting to run an IronRuby script from C#:

```
var runtime = IronRuby.Ruby.CreateRuntime();                  
runtime.ExecuteFile("ruby/foo.rb");
```

foo.rb starts with a "require:"

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'bar'
```

When I try this, I get an exception stating "no such file to load -- bar."  The file "bar.rb" and the directory "bar" are both present in the "ruby" directory.

So, how do I execute a ruby script that requires other ruby files?  I'm targeting .Net 3.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the ScriptEngine instead and add your ruby code files directory to the search path:

```
var engine = IronRuby.Ruby.CreateEngine();

var paths = engine.GetSearchPaths().ToList();
paths.Add(@"C:\Path\To\My\Ruby\Files"); // Add the path to your ruby code files
engine.SetSearchPaths(paths);

engine.ExecuteFile("ruby/foo.rb");
```

Comment: @Shay, @James: How do you suggest fixing the issue when the files in question are standard Ruby libs? I'm getting the above error when doing `require 'net/http'`.